# Reducing function name usage within function

Tags: javascript

When I search for a function name - it gets clumsy when I see plenty of function names as in the example. In large code base I waste my time when searching for how and from where a function has been called :

```
function do_something()
    {

        if (typeof do_something.flag == "undefined")
            {
                do_something.flag = true;
            }

        if (do_something.flag == null)
            {
                do_something.flag = true;
            }


    }
```

Here when I search for do_something so that I can look from where it is called instead I find plenty of lines consisting of `do_something.flag1`,`do_something.flag2` and so on which isn't of any use in most of such searches. In large function I get plenty of such lines occupying search output.

I've another scenario. In (Netbeans) IDE I want to do Ctrl-F `do_something` function looking for where it is called in the file. Now I find pressing F3 within the function itself iterating over it's own lines containing something like `do_something.var1=5` etc.

In short is there any way to reduce the function name usage within the function when creating object-global variables?

I've much longer functions but I'll give real example of medium level function causing this problem:

```
function slow_down_clicks(label, userfunc, timeinmsec)
    {
        console.log("slow_down_clicks=" + label);

        if (typeof slow_down_clicks.myobj == UNDEFINED)
            {
                slow_down_clicks.myobj = {};
            }

        if (typeof slow_down_clicks.myobj[label] == UNDEFINED)
            {
                slow_down_clicks.myobj[label] = {
                    inqueue: false,
                    lastclickedtime: 0,
                    login_post_error_count: 0
                };
            }

        var myfunc = function ()
            {
                console.log("Executing the user func");
                slow_down_clicks.myobj[label].inqueue = false;
                slow_down_clicks.myobj[label].lastclickedtime = new Date().getTime();

                userfunc();
            }
        console.log("Due to error in home.aspx reloading it", ++slow_down_clicks.myobj[label].login_post_error_count);

        if (slow_down_clicks.myobj[label].inqueue == false)
            {

                var diff = new Date().getTime() - slow_down_clicks.myobj[label].lastclickedtime;
                console.log("diff=", diff, timeinmsec);
                if (diff > timeinmsec)
                    {

                        myfunc();  //click login
                    }
                else
                    {
                        console.log("queuing the request after:", timeinmsec - diff);
                        slow_down_clicks.myobj[label].inqueue = true;

                        setTimeout(function ()
                            {
                                console.log("called myfunc babalatec");
                                myfunc();

                            }, timeinmsec - diff);
                    }
            }
        else
            {
                console.log("Discarding this request...");
            }
    }
```

Comment: Like `let a = do_something`?

Comment: No do_something.var1 = 2 or do_something.var2 = do_something.var2+1 and so on

Comment: Maybe search for `function do_something`? - EDIT: nevermind.. I misunderstood your question.. it's the other way around.

Comment: Is there more to this code? Because from that code alone, it doesn't make much sense to even put `do_something` in front of everything. Normally one uses `this` if using object-oriented programming.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I've added

Comment: Just search for `do_something(` if you're looking for calls?

Comment: Why are you using `slow_down_clicks.myobj` in the first place? Just put it in a normal outer-scope variable, not a property of the function object.

Comment: When I search `do_something` then it takes me to all `do_something` present within the function which I want to actually avoid. I actually want to search it outside the function. As I keep pressing F3 it touches each line containing do_something within the function. Assuming I've 30 lines containing it within this func, how much time I waste coming out of this function and keep searching beyond it? It's been 3 years programming this way

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use `this`?

Comment: I think you're making things difficult for yourself with your convention of attaching variables to functions like that. I've never actually seen that before, in many, many years of doing JavaScript development, and I can't think of why it would be useful. Perhaps you can enlighten me?

Comment: @Paul I can't use `this` because I'm using it as a function only. This function will have some common/permanent data which can be accessed as `function.variable`

Comment: That sounds like a bad design then.  You're using neither the OO style, nor the functional style. Bound to cause maintenance problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just define the fields as normal variables and put your code in its own file. Then you can just refer to the variables by its name inside your function because they are within the function's closure. The variables will not be accessible outside because you limit them in its own file.

like:

```
let flag = false

function doSomething () {
    if (!flag) {
        flag = true
    }
    ....
}
```

Put the above code snippet in a separate file and import the function when you want to use it.